# Getting the position and the pose of robot using tf_listener

Tags: ros, navigation, tf-listener, gmapping, stampedtransform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get position and orientation of the robot calculated by gmapping.
I used this question [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/10315/gmapping-get-current-robot-position/) and tutorial
[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29) as a reference.

I can get the robot position using **tf::Transform::getOrigin()** which is */map* -> */base_link* transform.
However the robot angle obtained from **tf::Transform::getRotation()::getAngle()** is only from 0 to π.
To determine the angle of the robot from 0 to 2π, What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39250/getting-the-position-and-the-pose-of-robot-using-tf_listener/) by [s-kawakami](https://answers.ros.org/users/2637/s-kawakami/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use [tf::getYaw](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a33e93f413622e296d0a2a93b252bbb4b):

```
tf::getYaw(transform.getRotation());
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11